# Monitoring Event Log with a Powershell script

Tags: script, powershell

I want to monitor event log for a certain event using powershell. 
I then want to send myself an email when this event occurs. 
An example: I want to monitor event 350 in the applications log. It is a critical error.

Is there a way to do this? I have the smtp portion figured out but am not seeing a place anywhere on Google that tells me whether or not this is possible. I dont want to tie my script in to event viewer. I want it to run in the background and loop every 15-30 minutes or so then email me once it detects a new entry for that event ID.

if this is possible I would really appreciate some pointers on how to script this. Thank you

Comment: Rather than running a script all the time on the chance that an event might have occurred, you should use Task Scheduler to trigger a task when the event occurs. The task would be your script that emails, or whatever you want to happen.

Comment: "am not seeing a place anywhere on Google" First result from [Googling "Powershell read event log"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=powershell+read+event+log) = MS Technet article on [Get-EventLog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849834.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you can find the event in event viewer , you may **right click it** then select  **Attach Task To This Event** . In "**task wizard**" you may got an option to "**start a program**" to run command "Send-MailMessage" to send E-Mail   .

For details please check [this article](http://www.ryadel.com/en/event-viewer-send-notification-e-mail-messages-with-powershell/).